# Proper way to atchive a Asp.net MVC Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm Just starting to learn the asp.net mvc platform and I don't really like to have a /home/ in the url.

Is there any way possible to have a route with just action and id for the home controller where if there are 3 actions (index, about and contact) the url reads localhost:1190/ , localhost:1190/about and localhost:1190/contact.

I know I can make them into separate controllers and just have an index view for each but is that truly the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But bear in mind that since the controller name is no longer part of the route, you can no longer specify it -> you will always have one controller - `Home`, which could quickly become overbloated if you start putting all actions in a single controller.

Comment: ok, thats what I thought. I was thinking that maybe there is some clever way to have a route that for home it will just need the action but for everything else it will need the controller and the action. -- Thanks

Comment: As a matter of fact you could use [`route constraints`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs). This way you could have 2 route definitions, one containing the Home actions in which you have constrained them to only the names you want to handle and after that have the default route in which you have constrained the controller name to anything different than home and of course the controller actions you have listed in the first route definition.

Comment: You can add more specific routes before this one, like     routes.MapRoute( null, "orders/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Orders", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );